# Powerline can be shown in multiple buffer, but not in a single buffer

Tags: vim, macvim, vim-plugin

I have just installed Powerline plugin into my vim by using pathogen and submodule.

The powerline **is only visible** when where are **multiple buffers**. When there is only one buffer in vim, I can't see it.

I wonder whether it is a bug or not?

[image: single]
[image: vec]
[image: hoz]

Answer (score 52, accepted):

What you meant to say is multiple windows not buffers.

By default vim is set not to show the `statusline` when there is only a single window. You can override this by using:

```
set laststatus=2
```

Numbers denote the behavior as such:

```
0: never
1: only if there are at least two windows (this one is the default)
2: always
```

See `:h laststatus` for more info..

Comment: oooo ,It's just a dumb questions , haha :) Thank you so much, I will accept your answer as soon as possible :)